# ASP.NET MVC: After Delete Action, Index is not rendering

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller which has `Add`, `Edit`, `Delete` and `Index` action methods. For my `Add` action, after the add, it redirects to `Index` in order to refresh the grid to show the add.

For `Delete` it is not redirecting. The delete is occurring, but I only see it if I manually refresh the page. I tried

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
```

and

```
w("Index", otList);
```

where "otList" is the model.

The is the code that invokes the delete action in the controller

```
    $("#deleteButton").click(function () {
            var button = $(this);
            $.ajax({ method: 'POST', url: button.data('url') })
                .done(function () {
                    $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
                    button.removeData('url');
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    magalert.communicationError();
                });
        });
```

Here is the `Delete` action method in the controller

```
    public IActionResult Delete(int Id)
    {
        try
        {
            var jurisdictionId = _user.Current().JurisdictionId;
            _electedOfficials.deleteOrgType(jurisdictionId, Id);

            //Refresh data post delete for the grid
            List<OrganizationType> otList = new List<OrganizationType>();
            otList = (List<OrganizationType>)_electedOfficials.OrgTypeList(jurisdictionId);

            //return View(otList);

            //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

            return View("Index", otList);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger?.LogCritical(new EventId(103, "CAdminOrganizationType"), e, $"Error when deleting id: " + Id);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why the `Index` view is not refreshing like it does for after the `Add` action? I tried to redirect and tried specifying the view and model in the return.

Here is the `Index` action method if that helps

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var jurisdictionId = _user.Current().JurisdictionId;
            List<OrganizationType> otList = new List<OrganizationType>();
            otList = (List<OrganizationType>)_electedOfficials.OrgTypeList(jurisdictionId);
            return View(otList);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger?.LogCritical(new EventId(101, "CAdminOrganizationType"), e, $"Error when loading Organization Types View");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're invoking the delete via AJAX, but also expecting the screen to re-load?  That doesn't make much sense.  Do you want to use AJAX, or do you want to re-load the page?

Comment: I fail to see the reason to use ajax here. Why don't you just submit or href the Delete method on the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are invoking the delete with Ajax you can't perform a redirection, one way to solve this is to refresh the page from the javascript code using `location.reload();`  When the request is successful after `button.RemoveData('url');`
Of course, if the delete is performed from the index page.

Comment: Thanks, that worked